# How to search records Solr with any filter option?

Tags: solr, nutch

I am using **apache-nutch-1.4** with **apache-solr-3.2.0**. I am able to install both and integrate successfully.

When I search word as **'Disease'** it gives result with fields like ***title, content and URL*** etc.

Now I want to search records with some filters for example.

I have a **centers page** which display list of centers like **cancer, Men's, Women's** etc

When user click on particular center like cancer a web page open which display areas and articles.

There is a search box with select box filter in which all areas of cancer appearing.

I want to search records with respect to any area filter that user selected.

Comment: can you add you schema and queries you have been trying ? Would help us to quide you

Comment: please find the schema.xml file here http://dpaste.org/MTDF2/

Comment: This question was suggested in the answer below: [Solr and facet search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357582/solr-and-facet-search)

Answer (score 0):

What you wanna do is facet search.

You can find a StackOverflow answer of how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357582/solr-and-facet-search)